# Tidying up list returned from xml

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, xml-parsing

I have xml of a cocktail recipe

```
<ingredients>
    <ingredient>
        <item>Vodka</item>
        <item>lime gelatin</item>
        <item>Sugar syrup</item>
        <item>Lime leaves</item>
        <item>lemon</item>
    </ingredient>
```

and retrieve it like this

```
ingredients.push($(xml).find("ingredients").eq(i).children().text());
```

This returns quite an ugly bit of text

```
0
:
"↵             Vodka↵             lime gelatin↵             Sugar syrup↵             Lime leaves↵             lemon↵          "
```

Can I convert this to an array or usable list? There are multiple recipes in the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you need to trim the whitespace around the items. To do this you can use `map()` to generate the sanitised array:

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<root>\n<ingredients>\n<ingredient><item>Vodka</item>\n<item>lime gelatin</item>\n<item>Sugar syrup</item>\n<item>Lime leaves</item>\n<item>lemon</item>\n</ingredient>\n</root>';

var i = 0;
var ingredients = $(xml).find("ingredients").eq(i).find('item').map(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim();
}).get().join(', '); 
console.log(ingredients);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```